# Regression with standard deviation dependent on predictor?

Tags: standard-deviation, weighted-regression

I got this question of how to deal with a regression model involving a set av predictors. The model wanted was one where the response should be divided by the (non-constant) standard deviation of the error, but this standard deviation is a simple linear function of one of the predictors (σ(x) = a+bx) so the response would be Y/σ(x).

The person wo asked me had been suggested to set up a maximum likelihood estimation procedure, an iterative one. But even if that would be possible, it seemed as a problem principally simple enough to warrant the search for a solution which has already been found.

Comment: Why would the response be $Y/\sigma(x)$? I find your description a little confusing.

Comment: Well, that´s not my suggestion, thats what the person who came to me said should be done. And it seems as if the people are are not that willing to consider other alternatives. But in case there are other ways to deal with this situation, i e a set up where the standard deviation is a (linear) function of one of the predictors, this would clearly be interesting.

Comment: Do you mean they suggested a transformation $Y^* = Y/\sigma(x)$ in order to make the variance of $Y^*$ constant?

Comment: Yes, correct, that's what they think they need to do.

Comment: Okay. Of course, what they mean is to divide by $\hat{\sigma}(x)$. The problem with dividing is that you end up with nonlinear functions relating the expectations. One needn't actually divide, since one can do a weighted least squares. Such a thing can be iterated in either case, of course. The weighted version could be thought of as a form of iteratively reweighted least squares.